# Spawning too many threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I just found out what threads are (at least I think I know what they are :s ). I'm programming in java  and I created a function that generates Strings. Every time the methode finds a string it calls the update methode and passes the founded string to it. (the stringfinder methode is a recurssive methode).

In the update() methode I want to process that string on **another thread**. But I don't know how to do this.

At the moment it looks like this

```
private void update(String input){
new ProcessThread(input).createThreadAndRun();
}
```

This works. But that isn't how it's done I guess, since the update method is called a few thousand times per second. And every time I create a new thread.

The createThreadAndRun methode looks like this:

```
@Override
public void createThreadAndRun() {
    Thread thread=new Thread(this,"processThread");
    thread.start();
}
```

But for the moment it is still spamming ProcessThreads, because every time I find a string , I create a new thread. Does anyone know how this can be fixed? So I only create 1,2 or 3 threads for StringProcessing?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, and for that reason, I can't help you.

Comment: it exactly do what you have written what you want to fix.

Comment: At the moment it creates a thread for every new String. It is way slower than doing everything after eachother because I've got a few thousand of threads. I don't think that's normal that a program runs a few thousands of threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is to run your threads on an 
[ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-). Consider the following:

```
ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

Then just submit your `ProcessThread` (which should be called `ProcessRunnable` or something) with:

```
threadPool.submit(new ProcessThread(input));
```

Comment: Thank you, :). Should i also add my StringGenerator thread to this, or isn't that important?

Comment: I don't know if this is normal but. I've got 4 threads (on my processor). 
And if I create a pool of let's say 2 threads (ProcessThread) and 1 thread for my StringGenerator.
I still get 100% cpu usage (it's about 10% idle).
Is this the jvm kicking in and spreading my 3 threads in java over 4 real threads?

Comment: With the work you are doing, and the probably rapid churn through the Strings as they come and go, you probably have the Garbage Collection thread running pretty hard too. That could account for the other CPU usage (the GC runs in many threads as well). Finally, the JVM often runs other threads as well as GC and your code.

Comment: Remember, you're talking to a newbie!  Don't confuse 'em with sloppy language.  One doesn't "run threads on an ExecutorService."  An ExecutorService _uses_ threads to execute _tasks_.

Answer (score 0):

You should use thread pooling. I think [this example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html) will give you enough information for your implementation. For more information look at [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

With thread poll you achieve this (paraphrasing): "With a limit on the number of the threads that can be created, the application will not be servicing your background jobs (worker threads) as quickly as they come in, but it will be servicing them as quickly as the system can sustain."

You can create fixed thread pool executor like this `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);`
and execute worked with something like

```
executor.submit(worker);
```

where worker is instance of your job class which implements `Runnable`or `Callable<T>`